# "For" vs "in": which will be correct to use?

Tags: prepositional-phrases, greetings

Context:

> 1. Good luck "in" your future endeavors.
> 2. Good luck "for" your future endeavors.

So which is right grammatically?

They are both on the internet. I am confused!!!!

Comment: This isn't really to do with "grammar" in the sense of "correct" adherence to defined "rules". It's just a matter of established idiomatic preference. We often use ***in*** or ***with*** in the exact cited context, but ***for*** is at the very least "credible" - it's just *much less likely*.

Answer (score 1):

Grammatically, they are both correct. However, the first form (using **"in"**):

> 1. Good luck **in** your future endeavors.

is more prevalent.